# Listview animated switcher

Tags: flutter

I am looking at building a list view which sort of shows list of titles by default and when tapped on it expands the same item to show more details. I thought of using Animated switcher and this is what I did

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: data.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            selectedIndex = index;
          });
        },
        child: AnimatedSwitcher(
          child: _listItem(index),
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

Widget _listItem(int index) {
    return index == selectedIndex
        ? Container(
            height: 300,
            color: Colors.black,
            child: Center(
              child: Text("Selected"),
            ),
          )
        : Container(
            height: 50,
            color: colors[index],
          );
  }
```

On tap it does change the widget but without the animation. I think AnimatedSwitcher cannot be used here, so how else can this be done ?

Comment: check `ExpansionTile`

Comment: Expansion tile has the title and its item below, was looking at sort of using the same item to show the expanded view.

Comment: so check how they expand the item [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/f9c825981c/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/expansion_tile.dart#L35) and implement it the same way (the magic happens in line #280 - `heightFactor: _heightFactor.value,`)

Comment: @pskink Thanks for that, I coupled the height factor with opacity too, so now the title fades away while striking and widget below expands at the same time.

Comment: its good, it works